# Divide a String and keep the "limiter / identifier"

Tags: javascript, string, replace, partition

On a quick note my friends, how would I reach this result in javascript:

We have: www.someurl.com/dynamicallychanging?page=2

so i am able to obtain the www.someurl.com/dynamicallychanging?page and the 2 with this :

```
            var number = nextSel.split('=').pop();
            console.log(number); //returns 2

            var basepath = nextSel.substring(0, nextSel.indexOf("="));
            console.log(basepath); //returns www.someurl.com/dynamicallychanging?page
```

but i would like to keep the = in the first part of the string so that I have this:

```
www.someurl.com/dynamicallychanging?page=
```

I have read something about partitions? Its been such a loooong day and I just wanna get it done and sorry but, after trying for 15 minutes, I think somebody here just knows the answer and it is super easy and helpful, as well for future readers they might find just what they are looking for.
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: `+ "="` ? or `nextSel.indexOf("=") + 1` ?

Comment: Sounds like you are actually looking to [get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979975/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var basepath = nextSel.substring(0, nextSel.indexOf("=")) + "="
```